# dplyr bug for select function?

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I´ve been working with R´s `dplyr` package on my dataset but for some reason the select function keeps giving the error of unused arguments. The function worked before and others seem to have the same problem that select keeps reporting the same error on a correctly specified function. Is there an alternative to select or how can this bug be solved? I can´t keep un- and reinstalling `dplyr` until it wors correctly again. the function is

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(start = 1, end = (which.max(Var1)-1)) %>% 
  top_n(n = 1, wt = Var2) %>% 
  select(ID, Var2)
```

is there a way to substitute select here? Thanks in advance

Comment: does it work if you specify `dplyr::select(ID, Var2)`?

Comment: Name collision/masking issue between `MASS::select` and `dplyr::select`, unload `MASS` if you don't need it or use `::` as Allan suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by masking issues. That is, some other package you are using has a function with the same name ("select"), so if you do not specify which one you want to use, R will select the latest defined name.

A very common example of this error that you can reproduce:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)

df <- tibble(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5 ,6))

query <- filter(df, df$A > 2)
```

This will throw an error, because we are trying to use the dplyr filter function and it is masked by stats filter function.

There are different ways to avoid this problem, but the fastest and easiest solution is to specify the package before calling the function.

Use this:

```
df%>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
slice(start = 1, end = (which.max(Var1)-1)) %>% 
top_n(n = 1, wt = Var2) %>% 
dplyr::select(ID, Var2)
```

Note that you may encounter this very same issue with other functions, so you should consider always specifying the package associated with the function you're calling. Of course there are cases where this is not necessarily the best practice, but this is out of this question's scope.